# Como enviar archivos de imagen con axios y react native utilizando libreria image picker?

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios

estoy utilizando la libreria image-picker para tomar fotos en mi app lo que no estoy pudiendo lograr es convertir el objeto que me devuelve la libreria a un formData para poder enviar a traves de axios

----Aqui capturo la imagen con la libreria---

```
    const takePicture = (documento: string) => {
    const options = {
        title: "Tomar una foto",
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: "images",
        },
        includeBase64: true,
    };
    launchCamera({
        maxWidth: 400,
        maxHeight: 400,
        quality: 0.5,
        includeBase64: true,
        mediaType: 'photo'
    }, (response) => {
        if (response.errorCode) {
            console.log(response.errorMessage);
            setImage(checkSucess)
        } else if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('el usuario cancelo la camara');
        } else {
            let objetoImagen = response.assets[0];
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('files',objetoImagen)
            //console.log('bat64',frenteDocumento.bat64);
        }
    })
```

formData me da el siguiente error: Argument of type 'Asset' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
Type 'Asset' is missing the following properties from type 'Blob': size, arrayBuffer, slice, stream, textts(2345)